# package iptracker/cmd1 is not in GOROOT

Tags: go

Hope find answers here. I'm trying a simple Cobra cli application with tree structure as below

```
├── cmd1
│   └── root.go
├── go.mod
├── go.sum
└── main.go
```

and the main.go:
package main

package main

```
import (
    "iptracker/cmd1"
)

func main() {
    cmd1.Execute()
}
```

cmd1/root.go:

```
package cmd1

import (
    "github.com/spf13/cobra"
)

var (
    rootCmd = &cobra.Command{
        Use:   "Cobra",
        Short: "Iptracker app",
        Long:  "IpTracker app",
    }
)

func Execute() error {
    return rootCmd.Execute()
}
```

My go.mod file:

```
module iptracker

go 1.19

require github.com/spf13/cobra v1.6.1

require (
    github.com/inconshreveable/mousetrap v1.0.1 // indirect
    github.com/spf13/pflag v1.0.5 // indirect
)
```

When I try running the code I get the following error:

```
main.go:4:2: package iptracker/cmd1 is not in GOROOT (/usr/local/go/src/iptracker/cmd1)
```

Go ENV configured correctly

```
GOPATH: /home/username/Go
GOROOT: /usr/local/go
```

I have run

```
go mod init iptracker
go mod tidy
```

But no luck. Don't know what I'm missing. I appreciate all your help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should write you go.mod file like this:

```
module iptracker

go 1.18

require github.com/spf13/cobra v1.6.1
```

Comment: I have a similar go.mod file as below                                                                `module iptracker

go 1.19

require github.com/spf13/cobra v1.6.1

require (
 github.com/inconshreveable/mousetrap v1.0.1 // indirect
 github.com/spf13/pflag v1.0.5 // indirect
)`